# How to thoroughly test a release build?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

I constantly encounter this problem:

1) I test my app thoroughly on many devices. Use Analyze and Instruments. No crashes. All fine.

2) Submit it to the App Store. App creashes all the time.

I realize the "release build" is something a little bit different than the "debug build". But how can I test a release build on my device that is built exactly the way it will appear on the App Store, technically?

Comment: Do 1) using the release build rather than the debug build?

Comment: @openfrog You'd be better off asking one comprehensive question rather than asking three questions, right after each other, that basically ask the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use TestFlight (https://testflightapp.com/), I have been working with it recently and it is a great way to test your Apps before going public.

You would be using the final IPA file, so won't be any difference with the build you would submit to the AppStore... Also, you could invite other people and they could download and install your App over the air, and even more, you have remote logs about crashes...

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there a way to build and run directly to the device, using the final IPA?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact it is, you can distribute it for Ad Hoc purposes and that way you will generate the final IPA. Download it directly from your device and install it. But I strongly recommend you to use TestFlight, it would make your life easier and you will have access to the logs.

Comment: I've just given up on TestFlight. Way too many almost-botched demos due to random failures during download and upload of apps. It's a great service when it's behaving. When it's not... arghh.

Comment: Do you use the desktop application for uploading the IPAs? Because I have had no problem with it, when I Archive an App it pops up asking me if I want to upload it to TestFlight...

Answer (score 1):

You can of course also **archive your build** (set the scheme to *iOS Device*, then choose *Product -> Archive*) to an IPA, sign it with your *Ad-Hoc distribution profile*, and **install it on your device** by dragging the IPA file onto your device in the Xcode Organizer.

When your Archive scheme is set to build in RELEASE mode, this is as close as you can get to test your final app without going to the App Store.

Testflight is doing the same thing, as you have to upload the same IPA to their website, so if you do not need to involve more people you can just do it local this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your testing Scheme (under the Project menu) to build and run a release build.  Or you can install an Ad Hoc build using iTunes if you want to test exactly the same install method as the reviewer.