# If I have the device ID for an iPad, can I build and send this app for someone to install remotely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, distribution, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Upon receiving the device id, what steps do I need to follow to ensure that the app can be sent to my client who has an ios device with the device id mentioned earlier. Then for the client to be able to install that app in iTunes on a windows PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Log in Member Center (http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) and add the new device.

2) Update your provisioning profiles adding that device to the list.

3) Archive your App for Ad-Hoc Distribution and generate an IPA file.

As I pointed here ([How to thoroughly test a release build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976600/how-to-thoroughly-test-a-release-build/14976788#14976788)), I recommend you to use TestFlight, would be much easier...

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an ad-hoc build with an ad-hoc distribution certificate that includes your client’s device ID. Then archive the build in Xcode and select the Distribute button in the Organizer window. The wizard then lets you save a standalone package that can be mailed to your client and installed there. For a service that makes this easier see [Test Flight](https://testflightapp.com).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create ipa file and upload on http://www.diawi.com/
for remotely install app.